# What exactly is a python library?

Tags: python

Sorry for such a basic question, I couldn't really find an answer through google that I could understand.

What exactly is a python library in laymans terms?  It seems like its something that you download or import and move into a certain folder to add a specific functionality in python?

If I download a library for python, does it go in /usr/lib ?

Any help would be appreciated I'm really lost on this!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)

Answer (score 4):

In Python, the term "library" is most commonly used when referring to *the* [Standard Library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/).  The Standard Library comes with Python and is installed along with it, making its *modules* reliably available to any Python code.  "Libraries" of code in the more general sense have more specific names in Python.

Modular components of code that can be `import`ed into your Python code are referred to as [*modules*](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).  The Python Standard Library is itself an extensive curated collection of well-documented modules.  Modules consist of Python (and sometimes compiled binary) code; they are packaged into `zip` archives known as *packages*, along with metadata, installation parameters, test code, etc.

Packages are the files which are downloaded and installed by installers.  [`easy_install`](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall) and, better, [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), are the two most common package installers.  These are user-friendly command-line utilities.

To install a package, for example [`sh`](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/), you would do

```
$ pip install sh
```

Depending on your operating system, you may want to prefix that command with `sudo`; otherwise, I believe you will end up just installing the module for your own use rather than in a system-wide capacity.

See the **INSTALLATION** section below for info on how to get `pip` running.

Packages serve to provide a vehicle for installation, testing, usage, and maintenance of the source code which modules consist of.  A complex package may include multiple modules.  Some packages will install command-line utility scripts in e.g. `/usr/bin` that use the module code.

Packages are usually (if they are mature enough for widespread use) distributed through the [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org).  This is where `pip` goes to find and download the package.

If you are looking for a piece of code to do some particular thing, try searching for it on PyPI.  You can also use `$ pip search '*text to search for in package descriptions*'`.  It will search the PyPI database for you and display the results.

### INSTALLATION

As mentioned above, there are two different command-line utilities which provide convenient ways to download and install Python packages.  `pip` is the better of the two, and requires that you have the `setuptools` package installed.  `easy_install`, the other utility, is installed as part of `setuptools`.

#### Installing the `setuptools` package

[Instructions on installing `setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/1.1#installation-instructions) are provided as part of the package documentation on PyPI.  Basically you download the file [`ez_setup.py`](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py) and run it:

```
$ wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | python
```

[Installation of `pip`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#get-pip) is similarly straightforward, **once you've got setuptools installed**:

```
$ curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
$ [sudo] python get-pip.py
```

Comment: Well documented is a bit too optimistic.

Comment: @Gcmalloc The Python *Standard Library* actually is quite well documented.

Comment: Agreed: I've read through the docs for most of the Standard Library modules and found the vast majority to be excellent.  Third party modules may not share this valuable attribute.

Comment: I don't agree that the term library normally refers to the standard library. Library normally refers to any package or group of packages which provide some functionality without being an application in themselves.

Comment: @MikeVella: I would say that although that more general meaning of the term "library" is sometimes used in that sense, it doesn't have a specific definition in the context of Python packaging.  So it's clearer to refer to packages and modules.  I've rewritten my answer to clarify this distinction.

Comment: @intuited I agree more with your revised answer.

Comment: The word "package" has many meanings. Package can also mean a directory with a ``__init__.py`` file in it.

Comment: @codeape: True.  I was hoping to keep it simple.  I looked for a link to provide for more info but couldn't find anything official and relevant.

Answer (score 3):

In a general sense, a library is a piece of reusable code. Most useful libraries concentrate around a single topic e.g. FTP, crypto, wrappers for APIs, climate models, database access, anything, really.

Python ships with a [rich standard library](http://docs.python.org/3/library/), with a set of core task. And there are thousands of libraries for more special purposes, that you can use, which are not included in the standard distribution.

(Note that Python terminology distinguishes between [module and package](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/111871/module-vs-package).)

Once the code has been written, it needs to be packaged and that involves a couple of rules. In fact, python packaging is a quite broad topic, as the [breadth of this packaging guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) shows.

Once the pieces of code are in a somewhat standard form and directory layout, one can call it a package.

Some people publish their packages on the python package index:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi

> The Python Package Index is a repository of software for the Python programming language. There are currently 34150 packages here.

From there anybody can install a package with just a single:

```
$ pip install some-neato-package
```

Now where the code exactly goes is dependent on you system setup. It might go under `/usr/lib/python3.2` or somewhere completely different, if you use some common tools, like [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

If everything goes well, you will have in a couple of minutes the work of many person-months at your fingertips, as you - once you installed a package - can use the library in you code:

```
$ mkvirtualenv throwaway
New python executable in throwaway/bin/python
Installing distribute.......................................done.
Installing pip................done.    

(throwaway) $ pip install requests # HTTP library
Downloading/unpacking requests
...

(throwaway) $ python

>>> import requests, re
>>> r = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com/q/18474784/89391')
>>> value, unit = re.search('(\d+) ([a-zA-Z]+) ago', r.text).groups()
>>> print('You posted this question %s %s ago.' % (value, unit))
You posted this question 26 mins ago.
```

Answer (score 2):

Python libraries are called "modules". These modules provide commonly used functionality in the form of different objects or functions. For example, there is a module that has functions you can use in your code to test if files exist on your hard drive; there are modules that have functions for implementing web-server, or web-browser functionality; there are modules to work with images; there are modules to create charts and graphs; there are modules to parse XML or HTML files; etc.

The idea is that there are things lots of people might want to do with python - e.g. read HTML files. Everyone could write python code to do that themselves, but that's time consuming. So smart people write a module that does this in a well-defined - and well-documented - way. Everyone else just has to import that module and use it. Then the low-level work (e.g. reading an HTML file) is done, and you just get to use the HTML file to do whatever clever work you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are talking about modules, which are a mean of collecting sets of features and/or custom data types. They exist to enrich the Python standard library, which already contains over 200 packages and modules (they can be listed by entering `help('modules')` in a Python interpreter. Modules are meant to be imported and used by your programs. As an FYI, modules that provide related functionality can be grouped together in a package.

Pypi, the Python Index Package, is a repository of such third-party modules. Chances are you will find an existing module for whatever task you want to accomplish, just search Pypi for for interests you.

You have two options to install them:

1. Download and install them manually (here assuming the module is foo-1.0):

`gunzip -c foo-1.0.tar.gz | tar xf -# unpacks into directory foo-1.0`

`cd foo-1.0`

`python setup.py install`

1. Install them with `pip` in a virtualenv environment

`(virt_env)user@computer$ pip install SomePackage==1.0`

The typical installation path on Unix/Linux is `prefix/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`, where prefix is by default `/usr`. On windows, it the install path is `prefix\Lib\site-packages`, where prefix is `C:\Program Files\Python`.